# Can entity framework be passed an open connection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

At my work we are upgrading our SQL servers and as a result are also changing the server names, now rather than go through all of our internal programs and update the connection strings we created a library that when passed an identifier string will query a crosswalk table and return an open connection to the program calling it. 
One of our contractors uses entity framework and is wondering if the entity framework can be passed an open connection instead of initializing using a connection string?

The code for our library:

```
var sqlQuery = "SELECT ConnStr FROM SQLConnStrings WHERE SqlEnv = @SqlEnv";
            var databaseConn = "";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@SqlEnv", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ConValue;
                sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 300;
                using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        databaseConn = sqlReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            SqlConnection conn = GetConnection(databaseConn);
            return conn;
        }
        public SqlConnection GetConnection(string databaseConn)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(databaseConn);
            connection.Open();
            return connection;
        }
```

Comment: On an almost but not entirely unrelated note, it is possible to configure server aliases in SQL Server Configuration Manager. When a client asks for a server by name, an alias can redirect it to another without having to change the query string at all. The downside of this is the lack of discoverability if you don't know that's going on, the fact that the server name must match exactly (it will not automatically match DNS aliases or IP addresses), and the fact that this only works client side (this may also be an upside).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EF6, you can pass an existing connection into `DbContext`.
Older versions can work with existing connection objects but they must not be open.

Offical documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-management#passing-connections-to-the-context).